# c++ How to automatically implement pure virtal methods in a derived class (MSVS)

Tags: c++, inheritance, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

I'm using VS2022 in C++,
I came from the land of Java where the IDE suggest me all the methods that must be implemented if I'm extending an abstract class.

I'd like to do the same in C++ with virtual parent.

EX: (java) - In Eclipse it works like magic

```java
abstract class Person {
abstract public String greet();
public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}
protected String name;
}

class Italian extends Person{

public String greet(){ return "Ciao, mi chiamo "+ name; }

}

class Brit extends Person{
public String greet(){ return "Hello, I'm "+ name; }
}

class German extends Person{
/* HINT BY THE IDE ASKING ME TO IMPLEMENT THE METHOD GREET*/
}
```

In C++ in MSVS

```cpp
//World.h
#pragma once
class Person{
protected:
std::string m_name;
public:
//method marked as need implementation
virtual std::string greet() = 0;
void setName(const std::string& name){ m_name=name;}

}


class Italian : Person{
std::string greet(){ return "Ciao, mi chiamo "+m_name}
}

class Brit : Person{
std::string greet(){ return "Hi, I'm "+m_name; }
}


class German : Person{
/* the intellisense suggest me adding a constructor but not to implement the greet() method*/
}
```

How do I tell VisualStudio to prompts me to add the method implementation (adding an empty one if possible)?

Comment: iirc in Java you declare the class to be not abstract via the absence of `abstract`. In C++ there is no way to declare a class as "this is not an abstract class", hence intellisense cannot know if `German` needs to provide an override or not

Comment: not sure, maybe intellisense can do what you ask for, but I imagine the false positives to be more annoying than the additional typing to add them manually

Comment: On Visual Studio, you can right click on your derived class > Quick actions and refactoring > Implement all pure virtuals for class XXX. It has not always worked perfectly though, e.g. for `noexcept` methods but it should be fine for most cases, including the one in the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, as a language, C++ isn't as tool-able as Java.  C++ wasn't designed to be tool-able, and at the time (circa 1979) tool-ability wasn't on the radar as an important feature.  So using IDEs like Eclipse, Xcode, Visual Studio, or the ones from JetBrains you'll see impressive tool-ability for Java (and C#), but rather sparse tool-ability for C++.  Better not to have an language assist tool in the IDE if it cannot be a rock-solid reliable tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the document: [Implement Pure Virtuals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/refactoring/implement-pure-virtuals?view=msvc-170)

> Mouse Right-click and select the Quick Actions and Refactorings menu
> and select Implement all Pure Virtuals for class 'ClassName' from the
> context menu, where ClassName is the name of the selected class.